# Highcharts - Color coded legend for solid gauge

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use the highcharts solid gauge, and I would like to have a legend, however Highcharts developers seem to have removed the color option from solid gauge series, which I believe is what the legend pulls it's color from.

```
series: [{
      name: 'Move',
            borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                radius: '100%',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                y: 80
            }],
            showInLegend:true
        }, {
            name: 'Exercise',
            borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                radius: '75%',
                innerRadius: '75%',
                y: 65
            }],
            showInLegend:true
        }, {
            name: 'Stand',
            borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                radius: '50%',
                innerRadius: '50%',
                y: 50
            }],
            showInLegend:true
}]
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dq2p7dw/1/)

Is there any way to get my legend to match the series colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to figure out how to color the marker in the legend, but to me the markers don't make sense in this case anyhow.  So, I've turned them off in my fiddle.

To color the text, you can use the legend labelFormatter function.

```
legend: {
  labelFormatter: function() {
    return '<span style="text-weight:bold;color:' + this.userOptions.color + '">' + this.name + '</span>';
  },
  symbolWidth: 0
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9dq2p7dw/21/

Comment: Thank you, I missed this function in the API, and I think you are correct, the markers are useless in this case, thank you for saving me the time tracking how to turn them off as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add, Barbara's answer is still valid in 2019. 
However, to remove the marker, you'll have to add

```
squareSymbol: false
```

I would have added this as a comment in her answer but I do not have enough reputation points.